# After do the function() to the image, do the same to the next image (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I want to make a slider which have opacity effect. So, the first image will 'fadeTo' second image, etc. But, I have no idea how to make the 2'nd image to 'fadeTo' 3'rd image when the 1'st is already gone. Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="pict4"></div>
    <div id="pict3"></div>
    <div id="pict2"></div>
    <div id="pict1"></div>
</div>
```

I want to make a stack of pictures. I arranged it from pict4 but the pict1 will be showed at the top, then pict2, pict3, pict4. Then the jQuery

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function effect(){
        $("#pict1").fadeTo(7000,0);
    }
    effect();
})
```

I have no idea how to make the `effect()` do the same to #pict2.
Any idea? Or should I use `setInterval()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will fade one after another.

```js
var i = 1;
var myinterval;
window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
  myinterval = setInterval(function() {
    change();
  }, 3000);
}

function change() {

  $("div#pict" + i).fadeTo(2000, 0);
  if (i > 4) {
    clearInterval(myinterval);
    alert("ended");
    return;

  }

  i++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Gradually change the opacity of the p element</button>

<div class="container">
  <div id="pict4">PIC 4</div>
  <div id="pict3">PIC 3</div>
  <div id="pict2">PIC 2</div>
  <div id="pict1">PIC 1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works for me. But, how to make the last image "FadeTo" first image?

Comment: tiara can you please give me some sample result so that i could better understand

Comment: I want them looks like the slider in https://code.org/
Your code works for me, but after it has finished the effect, it's over. I need it to do the effect infinitely (loop)

Comment: so you mean all should again display and continous process again?

Comment: Yes, btw, in your opinion, is my idea to stack the images less precise? If you think yes, I'll find another idea to remake the HTML structure and reask in the new question

Answer (score 0):

if you want to apply the effect to all images so you shouldn't use id selector try to select all `div`s by its parent like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function effect(){
    $(".container div").each(function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
     $(this).fadeTo(7000,0)
     },7000)  // you can change the interval as you wish

    });
 }
 effect();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

---

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<style>
#pict4, #pict3, #pict2, #pict1{
position:absolute;
display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div id="pict4">hi</div>
    <div id="pict3">kl</div>
    <div id="pict2">lp</div>
    <div id="pict1">hn</div>

</div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        animate();

        function animate(){   

            $('#pict4').fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
            $('#pict3').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500).fadeOut(1500);
            $('#pict2').delay(7000).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500);
            $('#pict1').delay(12000).fadeIn(1500).delay(3500).fadeOut(1500).animate;

        }



    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [jquery's doc](https://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) fadeTo accepts a `complete` callback.
So you just need to chain your callbacks

- Promise version

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls4k2r6d/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var pics = ['pict4', 'pict3', 'pict2', 'pict1'].map(x=>document.getElementById(x)) // or Array.from(document.querySelector('.container').children)

    pics.reduce((acc,pic)=>{
        return acc.then(_=>{

            return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
                $(pic).fadeTo(7000,0, resolve);//once anim complete, resolves promise, and next pic be processed
            })
        })
    }, Promise.resolve())
})
```

- Callback version

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ls4k2r6d/7/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function dequeue(pics, fn){
        if(pics.length==0){return fn()}
        var pic = pics.shift();//remove one el from pics
        $(pic).fadeTo(7000,0, function(){
            dequeue(pics, fn)
        })
    }

    //note that we don't use the div id so not needed to "sort" them by decreasing id order
    var pics = Array.from(document.querySelector('.container').children)

    dequeue(pics, function(){
        console.log('all done') 
    })
})
```